# Edit Instanced JList in an Instanced JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlist, jtabbedpane

I have a JFrame that has a JTabbedPane component. The number of tabs in the JTabbedPane depends on previously determined user data. Each tab in the TabbedPane is an instance extended by JPanel. Each JPanel has a JList and several buttons. How do I edit a specific JList?
How I create the tabs:

```
for (String s : variables.focusedHostnames) {
            clusterTab cluster = new clusterTab();
            tabbedPaneClusters.addTab(s, cluster);
        }
```

http://justpaste.it/maxv - The full class, called clusterEndusersGui

http://justpaste.it/maxw - This is the clusterTab class which is used to create the tabs

---

### **Code**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

// !! import assets.variables;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class clusterEndusersGui extends JFrame {

   // !! I (hovercraft) added this so that the code runs
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            clusterEndusersGui gui = new clusterEndusersGui();
            gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            gui.pack();
            gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            gui.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }

   public clusterEndusersGui() {
      initComponents();
   }

   private void initComponents() {
      panelQuery = new JPanel();
      labelWhere = new JLabel();
      comboBoxDataType = new JComboBox<>();
      comboBoxDataParameter = new JComboBox<>();
      fieldQueryData = new JTextField();
      btnFindUsers = new JButton();
      tabbedPaneClusters = new JTabbedPane();
      panel4 = new JPanel();
      listScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
      list1 = new JList();
      btnRemoveAll = new JButton();
      btnAddAll = new JButton();
      btnRemoveFromAll = new JButton();
      panel5 = new JPanel();
      btnApplyUpdates = new JButton();
      btnBackToConn = new JButton();
      // ======== this ========
      Container contentPane = getContentPane();
      // ======== panelQuery ========
      {
         panelQuery.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Find Users Query"));
         // ---- labelWhere ----
         labelWhere.setText("Where");
         // ---- comboBoxDataType ----
         comboBoxDataType.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(
               new String[] { "User ID" }));
         // ---- comboBoxDataParameter ----
         comboBoxDataParameter.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(
               new String[] { "Equals" }));
         // ---- btnFindUsers ----
         btnFindUsers.setText("Find Users");
         GroupLayout panelQueryLayout = new GroupLayout(panelQuery);
         panelQuery.setLayout(panelQueryLayout);
         panelQueryLayout.setHorizontalGroup(panelQueryLayout
               .createParallelGroup().addGroup(
                     panelQueryLayout
                           .createSequentialGroup()
                           .addContainerGap()
                           .addComponent(labelWhere)
                           .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                           .addComponent(comboBoxDataType,
                                 GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                 GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                 GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                           .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                           .addComponent(comboBoxDataParameter,
                                 GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                 GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                 GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                           .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                           .addComponent(fieldQueryData,
                                 GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 200,
                                 GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                           .addPreferredGap(
                                 LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED,
                                 GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                           .addComponent(btnFindUsers).addContainerGap()));
         panelQueryLayout.setVerticalGroup(panelQueryLayout
               .createParallelGroup().addGroup(
                     panelQueryLayout
                           .createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                           .addComponent(labelWhere)
                           .addComponent(comboBoxDataType,
                                 GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                 GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                 GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                           .addComponent(comboBoxDataParameter,
                                 GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                 GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                 GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                           .addComponent(fieldQueryData,
                                 GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                 GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                 GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                           .addComponent(btnFindUsers)));
      }
      // ======== tabbedPaneClusters ========
      {
         // ======== panel4 ========
         for (String s : variables.focusedHostnames) {
            clusterTab cluster = new clusterTab();
            tabbedPaneClusters.addTab(s, cluster);
         }
      }
      // ---- btnApplyUpdates ----
      btnApplyUpdates.setText("Apply all End User Updates");
      // ---- btnBackToConn ----
      btnBackToConn.setText("<< Go back to Cluster Connections");
      GroupLayout contentPaneLayout = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
      contentPane.setLayout(contentPaneLayout);
      contentPaneLayout
            .setHorizontalGroup(contentPaneLayout
                  .createParallelGroup()
                  .addGroup(
                        contentPaneLayout
                              .createSequentialGroup()
                              .addContainerGap()
                              .addGroup(
                                    contentPaneLayout
                                          .createParallelGroup()
                                          .addGroup(
                                                contentPaneLayout
                                                      .createSequentialGroup()
                                                      .addComponent(
                                                            tabbedPaneClusters)
                                                      .addContainerGap())
                                          .addGroup(
                                                GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                                                contentPaneLayout
                                                      .createSequentialGroup()
                                                      .addGap(0, 0,
                                                            Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                      .addComponent(
                                                            panelQuery,
                                                            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                            GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                      .addGap(98, 98, 98))
                                          .addGroup(
                                                GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                                                contentPaneLayout
                                                      .createSequentialGroup()
                                                      .addComponent(
                                                            btnBackToConn)
                                                      .addPreferredGap(
                                                            LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED,
                                                            GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                            Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                      .addComponent(
                                                            btnApplyUpdates)
                                                      .addContainerGap()))));
      contentPaneLayout
            .setVerticalGroup(contentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup()
                  .addGroup(
                        contentPaneLayout
                              .createSequentialGroup()
                              .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                              .addComponent(panelQuery,
                                    GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51,
                                    GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                              .addPreferredGap(
                                    LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                              .addComponent(tabbedPaneClusters,
                                    GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 390,
                                    GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                              .addPreferredGap(
                                    LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                              .addGroup(
                                    contentPaneLayout
                                          .createParallelGroup(
                                                GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                          .addComponent(btnApplyUpdates)
                                          .addComponent(btnBackToConn))
                              .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
      pack();
      setLocationRelativeTo(getOwner());
   }

   public static void printTabNames() {
      System.out.println("Tab Name: " + tabbedPaneClusters.getTitleAt(0));
   }

   private JPanel panelQuery;
   private JLabel labelWhere;
   private JComboBox<String> comboBoxDataType;
   private JComboBox<String> comboBoxDataParameter;
   private JTextField fieldQueryData;
   private JButton btnFindUsers;
   private static JTabbedPane tabbedPaneClusters;
   private JPanel panel4;
   private JScrollPane listScrollPane;
   private JList list1;
   private JButton btnRemoveAll;
   private JButton btnAddAll;
   private JButton btnRemoveFromAll;
   private JPanel panel5;
   private JButton btnApplyUpdates;
   private JButton btnBackToConn;
}

class clusterTab extends JPanel {
   public clusterTab() {
      initComponents();
   }

   public void getUsers(ActionEvent e) {
      clusterEndusersGui.printTabNames();
   }

   private void initComponents() {
      final JScrollPane listScrollPane;
      final JList list1;
      final JButton btnRemoveAll;
      final JButton btnAddAll;
      final JButton btnRemoveFromAll;
      final DefaultListModel listItems;
      listScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
      list1 = new JList();
      btnRemoveAll = new JButton();
      btnAddAll = new JButton();
      btnRemoveFromAll = new JButton();
      listItems = new DefaultListModel();
      listItems.addElement("Test");
      // ======== panel4 ========
      {
         // List
         {
            list1.setModel(listItems);
         }
         // ======== listScrollPane ========
         {
            listScrollPane.setViewportView(list1);
         }
         // ---- btnRemoveAll ----
         btnRemoveAll.setText("Remove all from Cluster");
         btnRemoveAll
               .setToolTipText("Remove all selected End Users from this Cluster");
         // ---- btnAddAll ----
         btnAddAll.setText("Add all to Cluster");
         btnAddAll
               .setToolTipText("Update All End Users, set their Home Cluster to this one");
         btnAddAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               getUsers(e);
            }
         });
         // ---- btnRemoveFromAll ----
         btnRemoveFromAll.setText("Remove from All Clusters");
         btnRemoveFromAll
               .setToolTipText("Remove selected user from all Clusters except this one");
         GroupLayout panel4Layout = new GroupLayout(this);
         this.setLayout(panel4Layout);
         panel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(panel4Layout.createParallelGroup()
               .addGroup(
                     panel4Layout
                           .createSequentialGroup()
                           .addContainerGap()
                           .addComponent(listScrollPane,
                                 GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 378,
                                 GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                           .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                           .addGroup(
                                 panel4Layout
                                       .createParallelGroup(
                                             GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING,
                                             false)
                                       .addComponent(btnRemoveAll,
                                             GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                             GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                             Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                       .addComponent(btnAddAll,
                                             GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                             GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                             Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                       .addComponent(btnRemoveFromAll,
                                             GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                             GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                             Short.MAX_VALUE))
                           .addContainerGap(187, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
         panel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(panel4Layout.createParallelGroup()
               .addGroup(
                     panel4Layout
                           .createSequentialGroup()
                           .addContainerGap()
                           .addGroup(
                                 panel4Layout
                                       .createParallelGroup()
                                       .addGroup(
                                             panel4Layout
                                                   .createSequentialGroup()
                                                   .addComponent(btnRemoveAll)
                                                   .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                   .addComponent(btnAddAll)
                                                   .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                   .addComponent(
                                                         btnRemoveFromAll)
                                                   .addGap(0, 0,
                                                         Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                       .addComponent(listScrollPane,
                                             GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 304,
                                             Short.MAX_VALUE))
                           .addContainerGap()));
      }
   }
}

// !! A dummy class that I (hovercraft) created just so I could get your code to work
class variables {
   public static String[] focusedHostnames = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
         "7" };
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "edit a specific JList?" What type of editing are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is no different from the more general question of "how do I get a reference to one object out of several", and one good solution is to put your objects, here your JPanel "views" into a collection, such as an ArrayList, if you want your items retrievable by index, or perhaps a HashMap if you want your items retrievable by a non-numeric object key such as a String. The devil as they say is in the details. As with most all GUI work, you should strive to separate your program's logic, it's model, from its GUI display or view, and this too should help you get and manipulate your core data.

As for the specifics in your case, it's a bit hard to tell, since you've posted a long bit of code in links. I ask that you please avoid using links as many here can't access them, and since you are asking volunteers for help, you should make it as easy as possible for others to help you. If you're still stuck, consider creating and posting here with your question a much smaller version of your program, one that has no functionality other than to try to demonstrate what you're trying to do, a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

**Edit**
I've reviewed some of your code, and see that your clusterTab, a class that should be renamed ClusterTab, declares most of its Swing components and their models as local variables within the `init()` method making these variables invisible in the rest of the class. Don't do this for key variables, especially the listItems variable, but instead make them private fields so that they have instance-level visibility.

---

Also, do not make your JTabbedPane variable static as that shows that your design is broken and needs to be fixed. The `printTabNames()` method should also not be static.

---

**Edit 2**
Some playing with your code -- you might not need the ArrayList after all if you're trying to get a reference to the currently selected tab since the JTabbedPane can do this for you. For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ClusterEndusersGui2 extends JPanel {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            ClusterEndusersGui2 mainPanel = new ClusterEndusersGui2();
            JFrame gui = new JFrame("GUI");
            gui.add(mainPanel);
            gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            gui.pack();
            gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            gui.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }

   public ClusterEndusersGui2() {
      initComponents();
   }

   private void initComponents() {
      someButton = new JButton("Selected Tabbed Pane");
      tabbedPaneClusters = new JTabbedPane();
      for (String s : Variables2.focusedHostnames) {
         ClusterTab2 cluster = new ClusterTab2(s);
         tabbedPaneClusters.addTab(s, cluster);
      }

      add(tabbedPaneClusters);
      add(someButton);

      someButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ClusterTab2 tabbedPane = (ClusterTab2) tabbedPaneClusters.getSelectedComponent();
            if (tabbedPane != null) {
               System.out.println("Selected Tab: " + tabbedPane.getName());
            }
         }
      });
   }

   public void printTabNames() {
      System.out.println("Tab Name: " + tabbedPaneClusters.getTitleAt(0));
   }

   private JTabbedPane tabbedPaneClusters;
   private JButton someButton;
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ClusterTab2 extends JPanel {
   private DefaultListModel<String> listItems;

   public ClusterTab2(String name) {
      setName(name);
      initComponents();
   }

   public void getUsers(ActionEvent e) {
      //!! ClusterEndusersGui2.printTabNames();
   }

   private void initComponents() {
      final JScrollPane listScrollPane;
      final JList<String> list1;
      final JButton btnRemoveAll;
      final JButton btnAddAll;
      final JButton btnRemoveFromAll;
      listScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
      list1 = new JList<>();
      list1.setPrototypeCellValue("                            ");
      btnRemoveAll = new JButton();
      btnAddAll = new JButton();
      btnRemoveFromAll = new JButton();
      listItems = new DefaultListModel<>();
      listItems.addElement("Test");
      list1.setModel(listItems);
      listScrollPane.setViewportView(list1);

      // ---- btnRemoveAll ----
      btnRemoveAll.setText("Remove all from Cluster");
      btnAddAll.setText("Add all to Cluster");
      btnAddAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            getUsers(e);
         }
      });
      btnRemoveFromAll.setText("Remove from All Clusters");

      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 4, 4));
      btnPanel.add(btnRemoveAll);
      btnPanel.add(btnAddAll);
      btnPanel.add(btnRemoveFromAll);

      btnRemoveAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            listItems.removeAllElements();
         }
      });
      btnAddAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            listItems.addElement("Fubar!");
         }
      });

      JPanel btnWrapPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      btnWrapPanel.add(btnPanel);

      add(listScrollPane);
      add(btnWrapPanel);
   }
}

class Variables2 {
   public static String[] focusedHostnames = { 
      "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" 
   };
}
```

Comment: Just coming across some issues. How would I edit only the ListModel that's in tab 3 for example?
Edit: Also just to note, the JList's data will be populated from a different class.

Comment: @xXTheAwesomerXx: MVC is the way to go. Create a "model" class for your tab JPanel view and have models interact. More importantly, work on the model and having them interact well independent of your GUI.

Comment: @xXTheAwesomerXx: also it sounds like you are now dealing with a *new* problem. If so, you should close this question by accepting this answer and ask a new separate question on this site. In the new question, please avoid links to code, and please post a minimal, or at least a much smaller runnnable program, like the one I created above. Not to gripe too much, but to solve your original question required much too much work to really ask a volunteer here to do.

Comment: Technically, my question was always "How do I edit a specific list" so that never changed. I think I'm going to redesign this anyways.

Comment: @xXTheAwesomerXx: yes, but how is one to get the "specific" JList? Via a combo box? via the list that is showing? You're leaving too much out and forcing us to guess, making this question very difficult. Again, I've put in several hours on trying to answer this question, and am a bit frustrated with the changing requirements. Please give more details on the specifics of your problem, and again, consider asking a new question with the new information better spelled out and with a minimal example program.

Comment: I apologize for this being frustrating for you, but it is frustrating for me as well. I've worked more than several hours on this. Thanks a lot for your input on this subject matter.
via the list that is showing? - Precisely

Comment: @xXTheAwesomerXx: then you can easily get that list. You know which JPanel is showing since the JTabbedPane will give it to you via the `getSelectedComponent`. You then cast the component returned to a ClusterTab object (as I show you above), and there you have it -- a reference to your JList. Doesn't that solve your problem, and if not, please explain more of why not.

Comment: That worked beautifully! 
ClusterTab selectedCluster = (ClusterTab) clusterTabbedPane.getSelectedComponent();

Comment: @xXTheAwesomerXx: it's what I posted yesterday in my example program above.